# List of NetSuite GL Posting Transactions and their recordtypes

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to obtain a list of NetSuite GL Posting transactions and their recordtypes.  I've created a savedsearch in my account against transactions and set the posting field to true, then grouped by recordtype.  This gives me a list of transactions that I've used (already created) that are GL posting.  This is not what I'm looking for.

I need to know all GL Posting transactions and I've been unable to find them in the usergroup or stackoverflow.

FYI, this is my first question for what it's worth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to go through help topic `Understanding General Ledger Impact of Transactions` or SuiteAnswer Id 7821